# What are the differences between gluProject and glhProject?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glu

I don't know why the [wiki of opengl.org](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluProject_and_gluUnProject_code) says "gluProject" in title but in the code is "glhProject". Any differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses `glh` because the person who wrote that Wiki page wrote the `glh` library. And technically, it's not accurate, since those are not how gluProject and gluUnproject are implemented. I'm strongly considering deleting this page from the wiki, so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Paul: Yes, really. `glh` is the prefix used by the GL Helper library that he wrote. It implements some of glu's functionality, but they're not the same.

Answer (score 2):

They just renamed it so the symbols don't clash on the off-chance you still `#include <GL/GLU.h>`, perhaps for mipmap generation.